# Laravel Eloquent ORM Relationships two tables displaying one column

Tags: php, laravel

I think I'm misunderstanding relationships, I have two tables one called invites and one called teams

Invites columns:

- id
- teams_id
- sentUserID
- userInvID

Teams columns:

- id
- name
- ownerID

What I'm trying to do is, display in a HTML table the name column from the teams table using the teamid column from the invites table to display each invite with the team name, so far I have set up a hasMany relationship so the teams table hasMany invites, and I have tried my best to set this functionality up but I think I'm misunderstanding Eloquent ORM Relationships, help please, below is what I have so far

My model, teams.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Teams extends Model
{
   public function invite()
   {
      return $this->hasmany('App\Invite');

   }

}
```

My Teams Controller TeamsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Teams;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Session;
use Auth;
use App\Invite;

class TeamsController extends Controller
{
    public function invites()
    {
        $id = Auth::id();
        $invites = Invite::where('sentUserID', '=', $id)->get();
        $teams = Teams::with('invite')->pluck('name');
        return view('team.invites', ['invites' => $invites, 'teams' => $teams]);

    }
}
```

My view invites.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">View Teams & Manage</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                        <table class="table table-hover table-dark">
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th scope="col">Team Name</th>
                              <th scope="col">Actions</th>
                                <th scope="col">Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                            @foreach($invites as $invite)
<tr>
                              <th scope="row">{{$teams}}</th>
                              <td><a class="btn btn-success" href="#">Accept</a></td>
                                <td><a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Decline</a></td>
                            </tr>

@endforeach                       </tbody>
                        </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

All I can seem to do with this code is display a list of names for each invite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `pluck('name')` you will get only the column values for the column name

You can try to restrict the columns via the `select()`. You can specify `name` column in the select clause, `id` column is required because it links the `teams` and `invites` table/records

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Teams;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Session;
use Auth;
use App\Invite;

class TeamsController extends Controller
{
    public function invites()
    {
        $id = Auth::id();
        $invites = Invite::where('sentUserID', '=', $id)->get();
        $teams = Teams::with('invite')->select('id', 'name');
        return view('team.invites', ['invites' => $invites, 'teams' => $teams]);

    }
}
```

However, since you are iterating over the $invites in the blade and need only the name value from team column you can use eager loading and load the team record with the invite query

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Teams;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Session;
use Auth;
use App\Invite;

class TeamsController extends Controller
{
    public function invites()
    {
        $id = Auth::id();
        $invites = Invite::where('sentUserID', '=', $id)
            ->with('team:id,name')
            ->get();
        
        return view('team.invites', ['invites' => $invites]);
    }
}
```

And in the blade view

```
//...
@foreach($invites as $invite)
    <th scope="row">{{ $invite->team->name }}</th>
    <td>
        <a class="btn btn-success" href="#">Accept</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Decline</a>
    </td>
@endforeach
//...
```

The relations as apparent from your table structure can be defined as follows

```php
class Team extends Model
{
    public function invites()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Invite::class);
    }
}


class Invite extends Model
{
    public function team()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Team::class);
    }
}
```

As per the table structure in your question the relation can be either

- Team hasOne Invite OR Team hasMany Invite(s)
- Invite belongsTo Team

If an Invite can have many Team(s) and Team can have many Invite(s), then it becomes a Many-to-Many relation and to implement it you need a different table structure with a pivot table `invite_team`

Comment: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (0) is the error I'm getting now

Comment: Which line is causing the error? Can you look in the stack trace and check?

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'teams.invite_id' in 'where clause' (42S22) with the new code

Comment: Have updated the answer with relations possible for the table structure you have. Pls check

Comment: Fixed it, i didnt realise you had changed the view code